# Get two values ​from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, json-query

I have a table called Register

***Id, Type_status, Status, Description***

Example:

```
ID      Type_status   Status    Description
1       8000          8017      test
```

And i have a table called History with the following structure

***Id, Id_Register, History_status, Payload***

Example

```
Id      Id_Register   History_status    Payload
1       1             8015              {"name": "test"}
2       1             8016              {"token": "example"} 
3       1             8017              {"email": "test@test.com"}
```

What I need is to be able to execute a query that will bring me the value of `Record_Id` and `Payload` value from the History table when the `Id_Register = 1` and the `History_status` is `8015` and `8017` with `History_status` 8017 is `email = test@test.com`

The expected result is

```
Id_Register      Name    Token
1                test.   example
```

I need to get all the names and token of the records that in the 8017 state have as email `test@test.com`

Mention that I have already solved the comparison of the text in the json, what I could not achieve is the query to obtain the two values for the same table depending on the states that I mention.

```
JSON_VALUE(cast(Payload as nvarchar(max)), '$.email') LIKE '%test@test.com%'
```

Comment: So what's the final output supposed to look like?

Comment: Perhaps you need to normalise the payload column into something like payload type and payload value

Comment: @Mureinik update!

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: @PeterSmith How to compare the json value I have already solved it, but what I can't get is to get the values of both registers for 1 only Register_Id...

Comment: Sorry, use Sql server 2016

Comment: Nothing in your data is called `Record_Id`.  What is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join twice the table History with the table Register. The first join will get you the names, and the second the tokens. To differentiate each one you use aliases.

```
select R.Id, 
       json_value(N.Payload, '$.Name') as Name, 
       json_value(T.Payload, '$.Token') as Token
from Register as R
     left join History as N on N.Id_Register = R.Id and 
                               substring(N.Payload, 1, 8) = '{"Name":'
     left join History as T on T.Id_Register = R.Id and 
                               substring(T.Payload, 1, 9) = '{"Token":'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this entry in the SQL server manual can help you, this entry shows you how to obtain a scalar value from a JSON column, so you can get only the email address from the json and use it in your where clause to filter. The best title for this question would be how to get a specific entry from a json column, something like that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Leandro, thanks for your response. The truth is that the problem is not obtaining the JSON value, but the query itself, being able to access both records of the same table but with the record ID in common.